# div box not growing on height

Tags: css, html

What would the issue be with the blue box and the white div not expanding when there is more content present.

I have placed the CSS of the area I am working on but it could not be the issue.

I am wanting the box's to be the same height as the deals categories that expand outside the box.

**CSS:**

```
.content_inner{
    height: auto;
    background-color: #6c93b8;
    margin:12px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    clear:both;
}

.homeWrapper{
    padding: 12px;
    width:auto;
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(71,95,124) 73%, rgb(33,50,86) 85%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(71,95,124) 73%, rgb(33,50,86) 85%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(71,95,124) 73%, rgb(33,50,86) 85%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(71,95,124) 73%, rgb(33,50,86) 85%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(71,95,124) 73%, rgb(33,50,86) 85%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.73, rgb(71,95,124)),
    color-stop(0.85, rgb(33,50,86))
);

.leftColBlog{
    display: inline-block;
    width:650px;
    margin:0 0 5px 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.rightColBlog{
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    width:230px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

**Issue:**

[image]

**[Live URL](http://agrilife.co.nz/deals)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to add `overflow: hidden;` to `.homeWrapper` and `.content_inner`

This creates a new block-formatting context for the right hand menu, as floated elements are taken out of the normal flow and require clearing or a container with an overflow value other than visible to flow with other elements.

http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/7868/sitetow.jpg